# Mobile First application does not deploy

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using IBM mobile first, I've spent some time trying to configure Eclipse to get it to work.  Switched the path to java 7, downloaded Eclipse kepler and hardcoded the local host into the server settings.  Not receiving any errors, below is what the console is reporting

> [2015-11-17 20:49:15]             Resource
>   conf/jndi/default.properties not found. This is not an error. Context
>   path is /
>   [2015-11-17 20:49:15]             Resource
>   conf/jndi/default.properties not found. This is not an error. Context
>   path is **globalscope**
>   [2015-11-17 20:53:45]             Starting
>   build process: application 'INSURANCE_APP', all environments 
>   [2015-11-17 20:54:59]             Application 'INSURANCE_APP' with all
>   environments build finished. 
>   [2015-11-17 20:54:59]
>   Deploying application 'INSURANCE_APP' with all environments to
>   MobileFirst Server...
>   [2015-11-17 20:55:06]             Application
>   'INSURANCE_APP' deployed successfully with all environments
>   [2015-11-17 20:55:51]             Opening preview of 'INSURANCE_APP',
>   environment 'common'

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no error in the log you provided. Are you saying you deploy the app but you don't see the app in the console? Provide your project then, or clearer reproduction steps.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

In fact, from the log provided in the question it sounds like deployment *did pass* - did not fail.

To deploy an environment first add an environment (right-click on the app folder > Add MobileFirst environment). Then right-click on the app folder and right-click > Run As > Run on MobileFirst Development Server).